# Can't Find Computer's unique ID AD Attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get the "Computer's unique ID" attribute from Active Directory Users and Computers.

The value of Computer's unique ID is `4C4C4544-0039-5310-8031-B9C04F393253`

I have the following code:

```
$endpoint = "someEndpoint"
$directorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$directorySearcher.PageSize = 100
$directorySearcher.SearchScope = [System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope]::Subtree
$directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn=$endpoint)"

$result = $directorySearcher.FindOne()

$result.Properties["objectguid"] # {30 103 159 141 234 5 102 71 128 215 212 4 206 254 198 63}
# Converted to hex = 1E679F8D-EA05-6647-80D7-D404CEFEC63F

$result.Properties["objectsid"] # {1 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 21 0 0 0 160 13 253 83 27 146 29 52 250 235 11 116 142 150 12 0}
# Converted to hex = 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 15 0 0 0 A0 D FD 53 1B 92 1D 34 FA EB B 74 8E 96 C 0

$result.Properties["netbootguid"] # {68 69 76 76 57 0 16 83 128 49 185 192 79 57 50 83}
# Converted to hex = 44 45 4C 4C 39 00 10 53 80 31 B9 C0 4F 39 32 53
```

From all the properties, the only 3 with a guid/array of bytes were the above 3.

However none of those 3 match the value I got from the Active Directory Users and Computers GUI.

Does anyone know how I can access the Computer's unique ID attribute from PowerShell?

Comment: By Unique ID I will assume you mean GUID/UUID? Do you have access to the AD cmdlets? `Get-ADComputer $endpoint | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ObjectGUID`. Also [this](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/maikkoster/archive/2009/12/15/finding-computer-in-active-directory-based-on-the-netbootguid.aspx) suggests that the value is stored differently than displayed which is why your last example is close

Comment: `$result.Properties["netbootguid"]` looks like the Computer's unique ID you got with some weird endian things going on in the first three groups.

Comment: @BaconBits check the link in my comment. It covers that and i think links to a longer explanation. The bytes need to be reversed in the first couple of groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the AD powershell cmdlets you can run the following statement:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter {objectclass -eq "computer"} | where { $_.Name -eq "COMPUTERNAME" } | Select ObjectGuid
```

This returns the unique ID I see in Active Directory Users and Computers GUI.

Also just to let you know, the last one (netbootguid) is your actual GUID you want. You can't directly convert to hex like you have.

If you want proof open up a powershell command prompt, create a byte array with netbootguid:

```
[byte[]]$array5 = 68,69,76,76,57,0,16,83,128,49,185,192,79,57,50,83
New-Object -TypeName System.Guid -ArgumentList @(,$array5)
```

The output is:

```
Guid
----
4c4c4544-0039-5310-8031-b9c04f393253
```

Comment: Thankyou. So basically when converting an array of Bytes to a guid you need to create a Guid object and pass in the byte array to the constructor! Rather than converting it yourself (because of the weird endianess in the first few bytes).